What does the accuracy property mean in the GeolocationCoordinates object on Chrome
When I run this code
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    console.log(position)
})

I get this object
{ 
    coords : GeolocationCoordinates
    accuracy : 11.479
    altitude : null
    altitudeAccuracy : null
    heading : null
    latitude : 36.8058487
    longitude : -119.8682803
    speed : null
}

How exactly is the accuracy attribute calculated? What does it mean?
